# Grails 2.0 inject bean and got ClassCastException Error in Controller

Tags: spring, grails

I have the following bean to inject to all the controllers

```
beans = {
   db(my.DatabaseRepo) { singleton true }
}
```

when I define

```
class MyController {
   def db 
   index() {
   }
}
```

I got the following error

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: my.DatabaseRepo cannot be cast to groovy.lang.Closure
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-7800 and is fixed, so this won't be a problem in M2. As a temporary workaround you can import the class of the bean and explicitly type it instead of using 'def':

```
import my.DatabaseRepo

class MyController {

   DatabaseRepo db

   index() {
   }
}
```